# Force recv (Windows C++) function to block until N bytes are read

Tags: c++, windows, tcp, client-server

I am using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=vs.85).aspx) code for a client-server architecture. Code runs easily without any problems. However, TCP breaks big packets into multiple smaller ones. The issue is from recv function. I am pretty new to Windows programming and wanted to know if there is anything like read function that blocks until it reads all the N bytes from a client socket (as it is in Linux when you want to read from a client socket fd). Any ideas?

Comment: As per [recv documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can use the `MSG_WAITALL` flag to wait for the buffer to be completely filled.

Comment: My god I read that thing and I missed it! Long day :)). Thanks!

Comment: @Kenney it is okay to make this an answer so that it can be upvoted and accepted.  It does not matter that it is trivial.

Comment: @Mike Okay, thank you - I wasn't sure!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Windows `recv` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) lists a `MSG_WAITALL` flag that will make the call wait until the given buffer is completely filled:

> **MSG_WAITALL**
> The receive request will complete only when one of the following events occurs:
>
> - The buffer supplied by the caller is completely full.
> - The connection has been closed.
> - The request has been canceled or an error occurred.

Example:

```
iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, MSG_WAITALL);
```